# Proving the size of the intersect of two balanced incomplete block designs cannot be equal to (v - 1)

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, graph-theory, number-systems, combinatorial-designs

I'm looking to prove that the size of the intersect of two (v, k, λ)-designs cannot be equal to (v-1). I'm aware how to prove this for a (v,3,1) design as;

In a STS (v,3,1) the number of blocks is v and the replication number is 3. So if |B1 ∩ B2| = v-1 then they differ in 1 block. But without loss of generality this means that {1, 2, 3} ∈ B1 while {1, 2, 3} ̸∈ B2. But since the replication number is 3 and all other blocks are the same we need a block in B2 which contains 1,2 and 3 once each. The only possibility is {1, 2, 3}; a contradiction.

I was wondering if this could be extended to a (v, k, λ)-design or if I should be taking a different approach.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The proof you give does not work for Steiner triple systems other than the Fano plane (the unique $2$-$(7,3,1)$ design), since in a general $2$-$(v,3,1)$ design you do not have $b=v$. (Also you would not call this design "STS(v,3,1)", it would simply be called $\mathrm{STS}(v)$.) But this technique will also work for any symmetric design.